# java regular expression extract pincode in address

Tags: java, regex

I have an address which contains pincode at the end.

How to extract *6 digit* pincode from address using regular expressions?

I tried using `String.index()` but it is not perfect. I don't know how to write reg exp syntax for extracting *6 digit* string from the whole string.

**Input:**

> 19, Jogeshwari Vikhroli Link Rd, MHADA Colony 19, Powai, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400076, Mumbai,

**OutPut:**

> 400076

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using pattern you can extract the pin code form the address :

```
Pattern zipPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{6})");
Matcher zipMatcher = zipPattern.matcher("19, Jogeshwari Vikhroli Link Rd, MHADA Colony 19, Powai, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400076, Mumbai,");
if (zipMatcher.find()) {
    String zip = zipMatcher.group(1);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to enclose the match in a group. You can just reference `group()` (which is the same as `group(0)` or the entire match).

Answer (score 7):

```
"\\b\\d{6}\\b"
```

Note that you have to escape the slash escaping the `d`/`b`.

- `\d` - a digit
- `{6}` - *6* repetitions
- `\b` - a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), used to limit the borders of the match. Otherwise a sequence of *7* digits would still match (as it contains *6* digits inside)

Comment: Consider adding word boundary around it. Ex. if address contains something like `Lane number 546417655, ...`